# python virtualenv ImportError No module named inspect time flask

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, configure, importerror

I recently deleted some old development folders off my disk, and now one of my virtualenv projects doesn't work. I noticed the problem when I tried to import flask.

I am using Ubuntu and I was using python2.7 in the virtualenv instead of python2.6 which is the default python.

I will describe how I fixed it, but I was wanting to know if there was a better way.

fyi I use bash in the terminal by default...

download source from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/

move source file into /project/src/dir and extract

change the working directory of the terminal to the newly extracted directory

configure and make

```
mkdir python2.7
./configure --prefix=/project/src/dir/python2.7
make
make install
```

create virtualenv and specify python to use

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages -p /project/src/dir/python2.7/bin/python2.7 projectname
```

enter the virtual environment

```
cd projectname
source bin/activate
```

get flask if you want it

```
pip install flask
```

test to see if we can import time and inspect

(bash)

```
python
```

(python shell)

```
import time
import inspect
```

test to see if we can import flask

```
import flask
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were using --system-site-packages before hand and flask was available via a path external to your VirtualEnv.

Keep in mind that older versions of VirtualEnv were not very relocatable either if they moved at all.

Comment: I have made that mistake before, but I am almost certain that I deleted the version of python my virtualenv was using.

Comment: If you still have the original VirtualEnv it may be worth posting information about it.. the file list and so on.. so that people can adequately answer you.

Comment: I probably misconfigured python2.7 when setting it as the default python in that virtual environment.